# How to install FDT plugin on Eclipse Kepler 4.3?

Tags: eclipse

I tried installing FDT plugin from their [update site](http://fdt.powerflasher.com/update/fdt5/) on Eclipse Kepler 4.3 but failed with this error.

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: FDT Core (required) 1.13.272.1632 (com.powerflasher.fdt.ui.feature.group 1.13.272.1632)
  Missing requirement: FDT Core (required) 1.13.272.1632 (com.powerflasher.fdt.ui.feature.group 1.13.272.1632) requires 'org.junit4 0.0.0' but it could not be found
```

UPDATE: After a brief search, I found that 'org.junit4' package is no longer available in Eclipse Kepler and has been renamed to 'org.junit4'. But I could not find a workaround for this.

UPDATE: This issue was fixed with the newer version of FDT Plugin.

Answer (score 1):

In the bundle manifest, replace org.junit4 with org.junit like [this](https://github.com/tobias-hammerschmidt/infinitest/commit/fbae7561702cf6f7eaac574836a8ec5740b09aba)

```
<Bundle-ActivationPolicy>lazy</Bundle-ActivationPolicy>

         <Bundle-Vendor>infinitest.org</Bundle-Vendor>

         <Require-Bundle>

org.eclipse.ui,org.eclipse.core.runtime,org.eclipse.core.resources,org.eclipse.jdt.core,org.junit4,org.eclipse.ui.ide,org.eclipse.ui.console;bundle-  version="3.3.0",org.eclipse.jdt.debug.ui,org.eclipse.jface.text,org.eclipse.debug.core,org.eclipse.jdt.launching
org.eclipse.ui,org.eclipse.core.runtime,org.eclipse.core.resources,org.eclipse.jdt.core,org.junit;bundle-  version="[4.0.0,5.0.0)",org.eclipse.ui.ide,org.eclipse.ui.console;bundle-  version="3.3.0",org.eclipse.jdt.debug.ui,org.eclipse.jface.text,org.eclipse.debug.core,org.eclipse.jdt.launching

         </Require-Bundle>

         <Embed-Dependency>*;scope=compile|runtime</Embed-Dependency>

         <Embed-Transitive>true</Embed-Transitive>
```